Discovery of a Formula for Geostationary Orbit Distance: Seeking Expert Feedback
I’m an amateur enthusiast without a formal academic background in mathematics or science. Recently, I stumbled upon an idea and derived a formula that I believe calculates the distance traveled along the geostationary orbit (GEO) as a function of the pointing angle ((\gamma)) from a point on Earth’s surface. The formula seems to account for the fact that the observation point is not at the center of the Earth but on its surface.
Here’s the formula I came up with in Latex: $
d = 2R \arcsin \left( \frac{\sqrt{(R-r)^2 + \left[ r \sin \left( \gamma + \frac{3\pi}{2} \right) + R \right]^2 - 2(R-r) \left[ r \sin \left( \gamma + \frac{3\pi}{2} \right) + R \right] \cos(\gamma)}}{2R} \right)
$ where:
•    R  is the distance of the GEO from the center of the Earth,
•    r  is the radius of the Earth,
•    Gamma  is the pointing angle relative to the vertical direction.
I’ve tested the formula for various values of gamma, and it seems to work well for the edge cases (gamma = 0 and gamma = pi), and it also shows an exponential-like behavior for angles close to pi/2, which makes sense geometrically as the distance to the orbit increases.
I’m curious to know what more experienced mathematicians and physicists think about this. Is this formula known in the literature? Does it correctly account for the geometrical complexities involved?
Any feedback, corrections, or references to similar known formulas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your insights.

Please take a look at Wikipedia

The distance traveled in GEO or any orbit is independent of where the satellite is observed from.  The distance for GEO is just $2 \pi R t$. where $t$ is the duration of the motion in days.  I suspect you have some different distance in mind than the path of the satellite

You could test this using GeoGebra.

"Traveled" from where to where? And what is angle $\gamma$, exactly?
